# Why does Leading/Trailing space show as -16?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

As I updated my Xcode from version 5 to 6 I saw a strange things in the storyboard. Here is one example:

- What my requirement was - I wanted no space between my view and the container view.
- What I did - I dragged the views left/right edge so that it meets the container margin. And then I put a horizontal spacing constraint.

Earlier the value used to be -
Leading/Trailing Space to:Superview Equals:0

Now after updating to Xcode 6 it always shows -
Leading/Trailing Space to:Superview Equals:-16.000000

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's container's margin. I think it applies the default margin to the edges. If you want to set up the `Leading/Trailing Space to Superview` constraint then you can do so.

[image]

If you have already created the constraint then you can select that constraint and uncheck `Relative to margin`

[image]

Please note the `Relative to margin` feature is only available on `iOS >= 8`, the app will crash (not sure but it should) on `iOS < 8`.

Answer (score 5):

Try to uncheck "Relative to margin"
[image]